# Copy constructor with a parameter as a reference to a derived class

Tags: c++, constructor

There is the following definition of the copy constructor:

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its
>   first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&,` 
>   and either there are no other parameters or else all
>   other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Note, that the definiton isn't concerned with the `convertions`, but the following program works fine:

```
#include <iostream>

struct B{ };

struct A : B
{
    A(){ }
    A(const B&){ }
};

B b;
A a = b;


int main(){ }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ec2320640a1dcc0)**

and it produces the output

```
B()
B()
A(const B&)
```

It's not clear to me, I expected the program doesn't print `A(const B&)`, because by the definition `A(const B&)` is not a copy constructor, therefore one is implictly defined as `A::A(const A&)` with default initializtion which doesn't produce any side-effect.

Couldn't you clarify what's wrong with that reason?

Comment: Your code does no copies. It converts from b to a.

Comment: As stated, the presented program should not print anything at all.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Maybe it's better to be explicit and say that it's a *converting constructor*. Or post an answer.

Comment: If I assume that each defined function would print out a message corresponding to its signature, the output would be fine. `A(B&)` per the given definition, is not a copy constructor. Since it is not declared `explicit`, it may be used implicitly to construct a `A` from a `B`.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Right, I just didn't know we can perform the conversion with the constructor (N3797::12.3.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as a *converting constructor* (§12.3.1). `b` is copy-initialized into `a` and `A::A(const B&)` is selected to perform the conversion. The result of the conversion is used to direct-initialize `a`.

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = b;
```

This would call the conversion constructor of class A.

```
A(const B&){ }   << This is conversion constructor for class A which defines conversion from B to A
```

Its same like we declare

```
A(int i) {}  << Convert int to class A object.
```

Even if you remove the relationship between class A and B then also it lead to that constructor call.